# FTPclient not find method

Tags: java, class, ftp-client

For some reason, he does not see class method retrieveFile

```
  public static boolean downloadFile(String Filename, String patch, FTPclient client) throws IOException{
        try {

            String remoteFile1 = Filename;
            File downloadFile1=new File("E:/Dropbox/"+remoteFile1);
            OutputStream outputStream1 = new BufferedOutputStream (new FileOutputStream (downloadFile1));
            boolean success = client.retrieveFile(remoteFile1, outputStream1);
            System.out.println(success);
            outputStream1.close();
            if (success == true) {
               return true;
            }
            else System.out.println("False");

        } catch (SocketException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
return false;
    }
```

But if the code is placed in the "main" method the same class, the method is seen.

Code:

```
   boolean success = client.retrieveFile(remoteFile1, outputStream1);
```

Error message (function "retrieveFile" not found):

```
Error:(99, 37) java: cannot find symbol
```

symbol:   method retrieveFile(java.lang.String,java.io.OutputStream)
  location: variable client of type FTPclient

Comment: Could you show working code in main method?

Comment: When asking about an error, always post the exact and complete error message. Don't paraphrase it.